# The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting "CS0012    The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    1_Views_Admin_EditUsers.cshtml  C:\Users\donald.dougherty\Desktop\Quoter\JanusQuote\JanusQuote\Views\Admin\EditUsers.cshtml 93  Active" for the following line

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerDetailsID)
```

It is in the reference list as shown in this screen shot
[Screen Shot with reference list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD1o5.png)

I have also added it to my Webconfig file

```
<dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Core" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089 Culture=neutral Version=4.0.0.0" />
            <!--<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.3.0.0" newVersion="5.3.0.0" />-->
        </dependentAssembly>
```

and the error is still there.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Donald